# Javascript is unable to access jsf outputText(label) element inspite of calling via id

Tags: javascript, html, jsf-2

I am trying to access the value of jsf outputText value using javascript but it throws undefined.Below is the code

```
    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="head">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function sendDetails()
                    {
                        alert("am inside js");
                        var key=document.getElementById('editForm:key').value;
                        alert(key);
                    }
                </script>
            </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
                <f:view>
                    <h:form id="editForm">
                        <h:outputLabel id="key" value="#{editController.details.clientId}" style="font-weight: bold" >
 <h:commandLink id="analytics" onclick="sendDetails()" value="View"></h:commandLink>

     </h:form>
     </f:view>
     </ui:define>
     </ui:composition>
```

When I click the command link it throws undefined!! I am not able to access the value of the output label.I checked view page source in firebug

```
<label id="editForm:key" style="font-weight: bold">
```

1e20bb95-753e-4252-b6d6-e109fa07171e

Which seems right..I checked with `console.log(document.getElementById('editForm:key'))` `console.log(document.getElementById('editForm:key').value)`which showed `<label id="editForm:key"> undefined`

How do I access the label/jsf outputtext value.I need a solution in javascript only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get `h:outputLabel` value with `.value`, because its being rendered into HTML `label` tag and you can't get `h:outputText` value with `.value`, because its being rendered into HTML `span` tag.

Use `.innerHTML` instead for both tags.

You can find all its attributes with Firebug. Add this to watch

```
document.getElementById('editForm:key')
```

for example, here are more attributes that hold its text

```
.innerHTML
.outerText
.textContent
```

Comment: Could not get it working with innerHTML or outertext but working perfectly with textContent...Thanks:)